# Isaiah's prophecy of 70 Years of Tyre

Tags: isaiah, prophecy

There are several prophecies concerning 70 years: one of Jeremiah (Jer 25:11, 12, 29:10 and 2 Chron 36:21) about the desolation of Jerusalem; one of Zech 1:12, 7:5 about the desolation of the Temple.

This question only concerns the prophecy of the 70 years of Isa 23:15-17, which predicts that the city of Tyre would be destroyed and forgotten for 70 years after which, it would return to its previous “promiscuous” way.

> At that time Tyre will be forgotten for seventy years—the span of a
>   king’s life. But at the end of seventy years, it will happen to Tyre
>   as in the song of the harlot …
>
> And at the end of seventy years, the LORD will restore Tyre. Then she
>   will return to hire as a prostitute and sell herself to all the
>   kingdoms on the face of the earth.

Does any know enough about this prophecy to shed any light - I have drawn a blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question only concerns the prophecy of the 70 years of Isa 23:15-17, which predicts that the city of Tyre would be destroyed and forgotten for 70 years after which, it would return to its previous “promiscuous” way.

Isaiah 23:15  (NASB)

> 15 **"Now in that day Tyre will be forgotten for seventy years** like the
> days of one king. At the end of seventy years it will happen to Tyre
> as in the song of the harlot:"

God through his prophet  Jeremiah, includes  Tyre among the nations that will be singled out to drink the wine of His rage. He says: “These nations will have to serve the king
of Babylon seventy years."

Jeremiah 25:22,27 (NASB)

> 22 "And all the kings of Tyre, all the kings of Sidon and the kings of
> the coastlands which are beyond the sea;  27 “You shall say to them,
> ‘Thus says the Lord of hosts, the God of Israel, “Drink, be drunk,
> vomit, fall and rise no more because of the sword which I will send
> among you.”’

Following the destruction of the mainland city by the Babylonians, the island-city of Tyre will be forgotten. True to the prophecy, for the duration of "one king"​, the Babylonian Empire, the island-city of Tyre will not be an important financial and commercial power.

The prophecy of Jeremiah  says:

Jeremiah 25:8-17  (NASB)

> 8 “Therefore thus says the Lord of hosts, ‘Because you have not obeyed
> My words, 9 behold, I will send and take all the families of the
> north,’ declares the Lord, ‘and I will send to Nebuchadnezzar king of
> Babylon, My servant, and will bring them against this land and against
> its inhabitants and against all these nations round about; and I will
> [a]utterly destroy them and make them a horror and a hissing, and an
> everlasting desolation. 10 Moreover, I will [b]take from them the
> voice of joy and the voice of gladness, the voice of the bridegroom
> and the voice of the bride, the sound of the millstones and the light
> of the lamp. 11 This whole land will be a desolation and a horror, and
> these nations will serve the king of Babylon seventy years.

Babylon Will Be Judged

> 12 ‘Then it will be when seventy years are completed I will punish the
> king of Babylon and that nation,’ declares the Lord, ‘for their
> iniquity, and the land of the Chaldeans; and I will make it an
> everlasting desolation. 13 I will bring upon that land all My words
> which I have pronounced against it, all that is written in this book
> which Jeremiah has prophesied against all the nations."

> 14 "For many nations and great kings will make slaves of them, even
> them; and I will recompense them according to their deeds and
> according to the work of their hands.)’”15 For thus the Lord, the God
> of Israel, says to me, “Take this cup of the wine of wrath from My
> hand and cause all the nations to whom I send you to drink it. 16 They
> will drink and stagger and go mad because of the sword that I will
> send among them.”17 Then I took the cup from the Lord’s hand and made
> all the nations to whom the Lord sent me drink it:"

Tyre , comes out from under Babylonian domination, and becomes a satrapy  of the Medo-Persian Empire under, the King  "Cyrus the Great."  Cyrus is a tolerant ruler and allows Tyre to pursue her former activities to become a  world commercial center, and compares her to a prostitute: "Then she will go back to her harlot’s wages and will play the harlot with all the kingdoms [a]on the face of the earth."(Isaiah 25:17b")

> Isaiah 23:15b-17 (NASB)
>
> 15 b . At the end of seventy years, it will happen to Tyre as in the
> song of the harlot:  16 Take your harp, walk about the city,  O
> forgotten harlot;  Pluck the strings skillfully, sing many songs, That
> you may be remembered. 17 It will come about at the end of seventy
> years that the Lord will visit Tyre. Then she will go back to her
> harlot’s wages and will play the harlot with all the kingdoms [a]on
> the face of the earth.

Will Tyre succeed? Yes, Zechariah 9:3 says:

Zechariah 9:3  (NASB)

> 3 "For Tyre built herself a fortress  And piled up silver like dust,
> And gold like the mire of the streets.

Why does God allow Tyre to succeed?  The prophecy of Isaiah says: "her harlot’s wages will be set apart to the Lord". God maneuvers matters so that it is used for the purpose of the will of the  LORD-GOD.

Isaiah 23:18  (NASB)

> 18 "Her gain and her harlot’s wages will be set apart to the Lord; it
> will not be stored up or hoarded, but her gain will become sufficient
> food and choice attire for those who dwell in the presence of the
> Lord."

The people of Tyre assist the Israelites that return from their captivity in Babylon, by supplying them with cedar timbers for rebuilding the temple. They also resume trade with the city of Jerusalem.​  (Ezra 3:7; Nehemiah 13:16.)

Comment: Many thanks, Mate!

Comment: It is my pleasure to share knowledge, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Optional info>>>. Nehemiah 13:16 really does not fit the context of Isaiah 23: 18  , which is a positive statement regarding necessary food and clothing sanctioned by God ; possibly for ,or during a transition period in the future times of restitution ,when mankind will need the food for an imperfect physical body ... As the general resurrection unfolds globally ! the common food and clothing needed for basic physical support and sustenance;  during progression towards a state of perfection on earth ! See Isaiah 55 : all  , and Isaiah 29:23 , etc. Certainly not achieved in a state of complete "nudity" for simple reasons !

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Answer (score 0):

what is a "Kingdom " ? defining Biblical terms is an interesting
pursuit ... Separate the literal -physical term and the symbolic or representative meanings to arrive at truth.. the"earth abideth forever" Ecc.1:4 / ...yet the Bible states in Isaiah 65:17 " I create a new heavens and a new "earth"..! terra firma exists to support an old global society ...and a future replacement ! Jesus stated to Pilate  in John 18:36.."My Kingdom is not of this world" (orderly arrangement ,etc.) Which is still here !

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).

Answer (score 0):

It was only old Tyre that was destroyed (initially on mainland by the Babylonians under Nebuchadnezzar in 573BC, but as regards the remnant island by the Greeks under Alexander in 323BC). At its destruction, the centre of global marine mercantilism (especially profiteering privatization of land & resources) shifted to London, the new Tyre (Isa 23:6, 60:9).  Isaiah's prophecy at ch.23 foresees Great Britain (London being the heir of Tyre) being 'forgotten' for 70 years according to the days of one king". This happened after WW1 as Britain's currency & military potency declined.  After the 70 years Britain sings as a harlot.

Maybe the 70 years relate to Queen Elizabeth II, who was crowned in 1973 (actually ascended in 1952) and has nearly ruled 70 years. However, maybe it relates to the rather strange exact gap between  Queen Vic. dying at 6.30pm on 22-01-1901 and Britain joining the EU by signing the Treaty of Accession in a daytime ceremony on 22-01-1972. This might look like a few hours short of 71 years,  but the prophet expressly stipulates reckoning of time to be "according to the days of one king", so we must look at the Israelite-Assyrian (not Egyptian) reckonings whereby a deceased king [Queen]'s notional reign was deemed to continue for the balance of the standard regnal year.

In January 2020 Britain left the EU (Brexit) and began greedily trading in a global (not European) focus, i.e. 'singing as a harlot' as foretold.  Interesting, the prophecy of general global economic & social depression [Covid?] in Isaiah's ch.24 follows immediately from ch.23 [Brexit?].   I definitely see Covid as just part of an inevitable process where human error will call down environmental, economic, fiscal, military, social etc. havoc. That havoc is unavoidable save by obeying the Lev.25:23 injunction (in its modern form of Site Revenue, where the annual value of sites privately occupied becomes the only source of public finance) and the other commandments, all of which necessarily involves recognition of Jesus as sovereign over 10m inhabited worlds (as updated for modern minds in Urantia Book revelation). No such recognition is going to happen, since the political will is and will remain absent in both the immoral elites and the wilfully-ignorant general populace. Tus, the End Days catastrophes of Revelation are to be expected.