# Isaiah 23:18 's “harlot’s wages” being “set apart to the Lord” an example of Proverbs 18:22 “the wealth of the sinner is stored up for the righteous”

Tags: isaiah, proverbs, intertextuality, money

( Remotely Related:  [Isaiah's prophecy of 70 Years of Tyre](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/47781/isaiahs-prophecy-of-70-years-of-tyre/) )

I might be asking the obvious.

> Isaiah 23:17-18
>
> New American Standard Bible 1995
>
> 17 It will come about
> at the end of seventy years that the Lord will visit Tyre. Then she
> will go back to her harlot’s wages and will play the harlot with all
> the kingdoms [a]on the face of the earth. **18 Her gain and her harlot’s
> wages will be set apart to the Lord; it will not be stored up or
> hoarded, but her gain will become sufficient food and choice attire
> for those who dwell in the presence of the Lord.**

> Isaiah 23:17-18
>
> New King James Version
>
> 17 And it shall be, at the end of seventy years, that the Lord will
> deal with Tyre. She will return to her hire, and commit fornication
> with all the kingdoms of the world on the face of the earth. **18 Her
> gain and her pay will be set apart for the Lord; it will not be
> treasured nor laid up, for her gain will be for those who dwell before
> the Lord, to eat sufficiently, and for [a]fine clothing.**

> 23:17-18 The Westminster Leningrad Codex 17 וְהָיָ֞ה מִקֵּ֣ץ׀
> שִׁבְעִ֣ים שָׁנָ֗ה יִפְקֹ֤ד יְהוָה֙ אֶת־צֹ֔ר וְשָׁבָ֖ה לְאֶתְנַנָּ֑ה
> וְזָֽנְתָ֛ה אֶת־כָּל־מַמְלְכ֥וֹת הָאָ֖רֶץ עַל־פְּנֵ֥י הָאֲדָמָֽה׃
>
> 18 וְהָיָ֨ה סַחְרָ֜הּ וְאֶתְנַנָּ֗הּ קֹ֚דֶשׁ לַֽיהוָ֔ה לֹ֥א יֵֽאָצֵ֖ר
> וְלֹ֣א יֵֽחָסֵ֑ן כִּ֣י לַיֹּשְׁבִ֞ים לִפְנֵ֤י יְהוָה֙ יִֽהְיֶ֣ה
> סַחְרָ֔הּ לֶאֱכֹ֥ל לְשָׂבְעָ֖ה וְלִמְכַסֶּ֥ה עָתִֽיק׃ פ

> Proverbs 13:22
>
> New American Standard Bible 1995
>
> 22 A good man leaves
> an inheritance to his [a]children’s children, And **the wealth of the
> sinner is stored up for the righteous.**

> 13:22 The Westminster Leningrad Codex 22 ט֗וֹב יַנְחִ֥יל
> בְּנֵֽי־בָנִ֑ים וְצָפ֥וּן לַ֝צַּדִּ֗יק חֵ֣יל חוֹטֵֽא׃

Would it correct to say that Isaiah 23:18 reference to “harlot’s wages” being “set apart to the Lord” a example of the Proverbs 18:22 generalization that “And the wealth of the sinner is stored up for the righteous” ?

Comment: The answer is, "probably".